# Falha no SqlConnection em C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
      SqlConnection ABC = new SqlConnection(
        "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dataRead;
```

Eu estou usando essa código para fazer um botão save em um formulário pra mecher offline e fala no começo

> Warning    1   The field 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form3.dataRead' is never used   C:...WindowsFormsApplication1\Form3.cs 23  23  WindowsFormsApplication1

e na hora de apertar o save da esse erro.

> Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Provedor de Pipes Nomeados, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL Server)

minha data base fica em

> Data Source=C:\Users\Somline\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PROGRAMA\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.sdf;Persist Security Info=True

Comment: Não tinha que ter o caminho da base dentro da connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto aqui não é um erro. É um aviso (*warning*):

> Warning 1 The field 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form3.dataRead' is never used C:...WindowsFormsApplication1\Form3.cs 23 23 WindowsFormsApplication1

Apenas está dizendo que você não está usando o componente informado em lugar algum do seu código.

Sobre a conexão, a *connection string* está errada. Se você quer apontar a *connection string* para um arquivo SDF, o correto é:

```
SqlCeConnection ABC = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=C:\Users\Somline\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\PROGRAMA\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.sdf;Persist Security Info=False");
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCommand();
SqlCeDataReader dataRead;
```

Repare que as classes são do SQL Server Compact, e não do SQL Server normal (`SqlCeConnection`, `SqlCeCommand`, `SqlCeDataReader`). Tem o **Ce** no meio do nome.

Comment: Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Interfaces de Rede SQL, error: 26 - Erro ao Localizar Servidor/Instância Especificada)

Comment: quando dou       ABC.Open();

Comment: Coloquei uma observação pra você. As classes têm o nome um pouco diferente porque são do SQL Server Compact.